# Why did filmmakers choose to make Sherman Klump morbidly obese?

Tags: character, the-nutty-professor-1996

In the [*The Nutty Professor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nutty_Professor_(1996_film)), filmmakers chose to make the main protagonist (Sherman Klump) morbidly obese as his main concern in his life.  The film is a remake of the [1963](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057372/) film of the same name in which the protagonist (Julius Kelp) has the main problem of acting and looking socially awkward, but is not overweight. Actually, Julius visits the gym to bulk up and gain weight.

Sherman Klump appears to be extremely shy and socially awkward in his own right without being overweight. 
 Both protagonists transform into the same alter-ego named Buddy Love who acts pretty much the same way in both films after drinking a potion.

**Is there any explanation from filmmakers on why they chose to add the problem of obesity to an already socially awkward and shy Sherman Klump?**

Comment: Apparently, the weight loss storyline was inspired by daytime television.

Murphy allegedly came up with the weight loss theme of the movie while watching a daytime chat show’s segment on the topic.

Comment: it was a pretty questionable source –– http://mentalfloss.com/article/60951/15-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about-nutty-professor and I haven't found anything else to verify it.

Comment: The movie is based on an older one called the nutty professor, in which he was a skinny middle aged white man, so they effectively made him as far away form the original character as they could without using an actress.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the weight loss storyline was inspired by daytime television.

Murphy allegedly came up with the weight loss theme of the movie while watching a daytime chat show’s segment on the topic.

This [link](http://mentalfloss.com/article/60951/15-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about-nutty-professor) is all I could find. I could find anything to substantiate or elaborate on the answer.